# My wireless keeps disconnecting in 14.04 (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, network-manager, intel-wireless

My wireless keeps disconnecting from the networks within 10 minutes after I boot up.  It keeps trying to connect to the network, but it fails.  I can see several networks at that time.  I then try to disable then renable the hardware.  I am unable to see any networks.

I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04.  I am using a Dell XPS L501.

This is my network controller:

> Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]

I have had issues in the past that I have resolved by removing iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode in the past.  I am currently using iwlwifi-1000-3.ucode.

I am currently dual booting Windows 7.  This problem does not show itself there.  I have also had this problem reoccur with other networks.

Using the script provided here:

> [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos?newreg=d0a2bb26a71646b7a54ad2c4daf751f6)

I have generated the following text:

> http://paste.ubuntu.com/14439608/

I have also found the following error in my syslog.

> http://paste.ubuntu.com/14439562/

Not sure if it is related or not.